# Why does 1,3-dihydroxybenzene have a higher boiling point than 1,2-dihydroxybenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

1,2-dihydroxybenzene (catechol) shows intramolecular H-bonding. So due to strong bonding, it should be difficult to break the bonds in 1,2-dihydroxybenzene and therefore, 1,2-dihydroxybenzene should have a higher boiling point than 1,3-dihydroxybenzene. Why is it not so?

Comment: Related: [Which among phenol and 1,2-dihydroxybenzene has the higher boiling point?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6482/7951)

Comment: The answer is in your question itself.Intramolecular hydrogen bonding will only reduce the boiling point as intramoleclar H-bond will not allow one molecule to link with another.Intramolecular H-bond two molecules are linked.For boiling up,the molecule-molecule interaction must be broken and not the bonds within a molecule.

Comment: @AbhishekPallipparagopakumar Then what factor decides the difference in boiling point among 1,2dihydroxybenzene and 1,3 dihydroxybenzene

Comment: Of course as i mentioned above catechol has **intra**molecular H-bond whereas resourcinol has ** inter**molecular H-bond.Thus there is no interaction between two molecules in catechol.Whereas there is interaction between two molecules of resourcinol.

Answer (score 4):

Being more volatile implies that the molecules should be **set free from mutual interactions**. As 1,2-dihydroxybenzene has intramolecular H bonding, it is easy for it to exist independently, but for 1,3-dihydroxybenzene there might be intermolecular H bonding (interaction between two molecules); hence, it is a bit more difficult to break it apart, thus having a higher boiling point than its counterpart.